# "btn-outline-primary" not working in bootstrap cdm

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using this CDN "  " but using this " outline " is not working in bootstrap button. But while using the bootstrap website's link then this is working but then in navbar portion " navbar-default " is not working. Why it is behaving like this ? I can not find ant solution.

Comment: Can you show us the code where your cdn is located at?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">
  </head>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-head">
        <p class="navbar-brand">Test WebPage</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap 3. Try changing the link to cdn for Bootstrap 4. Here is the cdn link
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css